# wcf communication error using code

Tags: c#, wcf

i have the following **Host** config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="VersionManager.Services.ClientRepository">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8740/ClientRepository/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="VersionManager.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IClientRepository">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8740/ClientRepository/" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

in the client side, since i want to dynamically set the address from a file, i'm using code 
to connect.
but it fails to connect...

this is the code i'm trying to use:

```
Callback = new ClientRepositoryCallback();

_context = new InstanceContext(Callback);

var proxy = new DuplexChannelFactory<IClientRepository>(_context,
                                                        new WSDualHttpBinding(
                                                            "WSDualHttpBinding_IClientRepository"),
                                                        new EndpointAddress(new Uri(serverAddress)));

var channel = proxy.CreateChannel();
channel.Ping(Station);
```

it seems like the channel is created successfully, but when i'm trying to use the Ping() method on the contract it fails with Timeout exception.

```
{System.TimeoutException: This request operation sent to http://localhost:8740/ClientRepository/ did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:00:59.9830000).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.SyncDuplexRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at DirectoryScanner.Infrastrcuture.ServerProxy.IClientRepository.Ping(Station station)
   at DirectoryScanner.Services.ClientRepository..ctor() in ClientRepository.cs:line 96}
```

the client app.config file is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IClientRepository" />
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IClientRepository"
          contract="ServerProxy.IClientRepository" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IClientRepository">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

it works well using the auto generated app.config on the client, but since i want to use a parameter for the host i need to use code...

Comment: If you write in ie http://localhost:8740/ClientRepository/myservice.svc brings you something?

Comment: i don't have .svc anywhere... maybe it's related to asp.net ? this is WPF application

Comment: i have updated the post with the current app.config in the client

Comment: wcf is related with wcf services. Maybe is a web api. When you enter in ie http://localhost:8740/ClientRepositor/ does it bring you somthing?

Comment: yes. i get ClientRepository Service html page